# How to define open vector in Julia

Tags: julia

In Julia, when I type `collect(1:4)`, this will immediately give me a vector containing all the numbers `1,2,3,4`. My question is that what is the syntax in Julia such that I can define an open vector so that the return is `2,3,4` or `1,2,3` or `2,3`.

Comment: Related question: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-can-i-define-a-half-open-interval-in-julia-and-test-for-containment/72787

Answer (score 3):

This is may not be what you had in mind but here are the syntaxes for various inclusive and exclusive ranges from `a` to `b`:

- `a:b` is the inclusive range
- `a:b-1` is the inclusive-exclusive range
- `a+1:b` is the exclusive-inclusive range
- `a+1:b-1` is the exclusive range

Answer (score 2):

I'm not seeing the utility of open integer intervals, unlike for floats. You can always just specify `m:n` for whatever numbers you need. If you want to strip a generic input range, `r`, do eg. `r[2:end-1]`, or similar.

For floats it is different. The half-open float interval `[1, 2)` is non-trivial to express, but open/half-open integer ranges just seem unnecessary to me.

Answer (score 1):

```
most(a)      = a[begin:end-1]
rest(a)      = a[begin+1:end]
innermost(a) = a[begin+1:end-1]
outermost(a) = a[[begin, end]]
```

It's looking a bit AngloSaxon. How about doing `midmost`? ;}